# Convert object to type without boxing

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

I am trying to extend the event aggregator similar to the one described in [blog post on Event Aggregator](https://joseoncode.com/2010/04/29/event-aggregator-with-reactive-extensions/) with Rx. Using the code from the blog post, I can listen to events by creating a subscription:

```
int value = 0;
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<Foo>().Subscribe(x => value = x.Value)
```

where

```
class Foo : IConvertible
{ 
    public int Value {get;set;}

    //Several IConvertible omitted

    public object ToType(Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return new FooEvent();
    }
}
```

Publishing a new event is also simple:

```
_eventAggregator.Publish(new Foo {Value = 1});
```

Now I need to wrap two or more events into a composite and publish those pieces of data in a sequential manner. My attempt strands here:

```
    public void Publish<TEventArgs>(TEventArgs eventData)
    {
        var composite = eventData as IComposite;
        if (composite == null)
        {
            _eventAggregator.Publish(eventData);
            return;
        }

        var convertedType = Convert.ChangeType(composite.OnNext, composite.OnNextType); //dynamic cast
        var castedType = (Foo)composite.OnNext; //static cast

        _eventAggregator.Publish(convertedType); //never received
        _eventAggregator.Publish(castedType);  //is received 
    }
```

where

```
public interface IComposite
{
    Type OnNextType { get; }
    object OnNext { get; }
}
```

The problem is that the event subscription is static and known at compile time, but the publishing of data is at runtime and the type is not statically known. 
In the code snippet, I try to use `Convert.ChangeType`, but the resulting object is a wrapped / boxed `Foo` object. This is seen in the screen shot of Visual Studio's Watch window.

[image]

Is there any way of dynamically casting an object such that the result is not boxed?

**Update** Besides what is in this code snippet, I have also tried (1) decorating Foo with the TypeConverter attribute using a custom TypeConverter, and (2) reflection + generics. In all cases, the outcome is of type `object` and not `Foo`.

Comment: only value types are boxed, not reference types

Comment: consider using a `IComposite<T>`

Comment: @DanielA.White Your suggestion was actually my first attempt, but in method `Publish` I then need to do `eventData as IComposite<T>`. This implies that method `Publish` needs to check all types of T, e.g. `eventData as IComposite<Foo>`, and `eventData as IComposite<Bazz>` and `eventData as IComposite<Bar>` etc. With 50+ types that is not very practical.